# Sorting the letters in a string by the order they occur?

Tags: algorithm

Is sorting the letters in a string by the order they occur doable in linear time?

For instance, `boyhood` would sort to `boooyhd`.

Comment: Yes, sort of. Walk through string, counting occurrences of each character (linear). Walk through again, and as you encounter a letter, reproduce it N times from the count, then set that count to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is an O(2n) solution in python:

```
import sys

word = raw_input("Enter string to sort:")
wordDict = {}

for letter in word:
    if letter in wordDict:
        wordDict[letter] = wordDict[letter] + 1
    else:
        wordDict[letter] = 1

for letter in word:
    sys.stdout.write(letter*wordDict[letter])
    wordDict[letter] = 0
```